# I am getting 'Invalid syntax error near +' , in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

It tells me I have an incorrect syntax close to the +sol_id+. I don't know what i am not doing correctly.

I am trying to model a stored procedure but it gives me some issues rather than get the whole job done. Code is looking like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindBranchVaultBalance
    @sol_id varchar(50),
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50)
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER,
                    'select foracid, acct_crncy_code, clr_bal_amt 
                     from dummy_table  
                     where bacid=''1010000001'' and sol_id='''''+@sol_id +''''' and acct_crncy_code='''+@acct_crncy_code+''' and del_flg=''N'' and acct_cls_flg=''N''')
GO;
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edits**

I have edited it to look like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindBranchVaultBalance
    @sol_id varchar(50),
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50)
AS 
    SELECT * 
    FROM OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER,
                    'select foracid, acct_crncy_code, clr_bal_amt 
                     from dummy_table  
                     where bacid=''1010000001'' and sol_id='''+@sol_id+''' and acct_crncy_code='''+@acct_crncy_code+''' and del_flg=''N'' and acct_cls_flg=''N''')
GO;
```

Comment: It doesn't look correct when you have `sol_id='''''+` but then the second one is `acct_crncy_code='''+`

Comment: i had the '''+ initially, was giving me the error before i decided to even add the '''''+

Comment: Shouldn't you then use it for both variables and not just the first one?

Comment: I edited it now. Please see edits.

Comment: `openquery()` does not support use of expression as parameter for the query. It must be a constant string. For you case, you need to dynamically generate the entire `openquery()` statement

Answer (score 1):

As mention in the comment, `OPENQUERY()` does not support using of expression as input, it must be a string constant.

For your case, the query is dynamic, you will need create an entire dynamic query for the `OPENQUERY()`

---

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @SQL = '

select * 
from  openquery (LINKEDSERVER, 
                ''select foracid,acct_crncy_code,clr_bal_amt 
                  from  dummy_table  
                  where bacid  = ''''1010000001'''' 
                  and   sol_id = ''''' + @sol_id + ''''' 
                  and   acct_crncy_code = '''' + @acct_crncy_code + '''' 
                  and   del_flg = ''''N'''' 
                  and   acct_cls_flg = ''''N'''')'''

 PRINT @SQL    -- print out to verify

 EXEC sp_executesql @SQL    -- execute it
```

Note : untested

Answer (score 0):

You have too many quotations surrounding the `@sol_id` variable.

The statement works as

```
select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select foracid,acct_crncy_code,clr_bal_amt from dummy_table  where bacid=''1010000001'' and sol_id=''' 
 + @sol_id + ''' and acct_crncy_code=''' 
 + @acct_crncy_code + ''' and del_flg=''N'' and acct_cls_flg=''N''')
```

In order to diagnose and debug Dynamic SQL errors it can help to use a variable and print it to check the formatting.

Try the following construct

```
create procedure FindBranchVaultBalance
@sol_id varchar(50),
@acct_crncy_code varchar(50)
as 
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql=Concat('select foracid,acct_crncy_code,clr_bal_amt from dummy_table  where bacid=''1010000001'' and sol_id=''',
@sol_id, ''' and acct_crncy_code=''',
@acct_crncy_code, ''' and del_flg=''N'' and acct_cls_flg=''N''');

print @sql;

select * from OpenQuery(LINKEDSERVER, @sql);
```

Check the result of the *Print* statement and if it's correct, try testing by substituting the `@Sql` variable for the built string

Comment: still the same Error 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure FindBranchVaultBalance, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '+'.

Comment: Have edited and added a further suggestion to print and check the result of your dynamic sql query.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone else has suggested, you can use dynamic SQL.

However, **you must escape the variables correctly.** Use `QUOTENAME` for this. You need to use it twice, once for the local dynamic SQL, and once for the remote side.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE FindBranchVaultBalance
    @sol_id varchar(50),
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50)
AS

DECLARE @query nvarchar(max) = N'
select foracid, acct_crncy_code, clr_bal_amt 
from dummy_table  
where bacid = ''1010000001'' and sol_id = ' + QUOTENAME(@sol_id, '''') + N' and
  acct_crncy_code = ' + QUOTENAME(@acct_crncy_code, '''') + N' and
  del_flg = ''N'' and acct_cls_flg = ''N''
';

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY (LINKEDSERVER, N' + QUOTENAME(@query, '''') + N'  )
';

EXEC @sp_executesql @sql;

GO
```

**I suggest you consider doing this as a standard linked server query, if at all possible.** It's far simpler, with no dynamic query required, and less prone to error.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE FindBranchVaultBalance
    @sol_id varchar(50),
    @acct_crncy_code varchar(50)
AS

select foracid, acct_crncy_code, clr_bal_amt 
from LINKEDSERVER.yourdb..dummy_table  
where bacid = '1010000001' and sol_id = @sol_id and
  acct_crncy_code = @acct_crncy_code and
  del_flg = 'N' and acct_cls_flg = 'N';

GO
```